# SSRS Rendering On Server Adding Whitespace

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a report, and on that report is a rectangle with a bunch of textboxes that are only visible based on a Visibility Expression for each box.

When I run my SSRS report on my desktop, or if I convert it to a PDF from the server, it looks fine. When a textbox is not visible, the box underneath moves up to fill the void.

When I just let it render through a browser on the server using (&rs:Command=Render) it's adding white space to move it to the middle of the rectangle so it is not formatting properly.

Here's what it looks like when only one of the lines is visible when it's on my desktop or when saved as a PDF (or image) file:
[image]

The red box is moved up to right underneath the black box when all the other boxes are not visible. That's what I want.

When it's rendered on the server, it looks like this:
[image]

It's moving the red box to the middle of the rectangle for some reason.

It's not the browser, I've tried 3 and it looks the same in all of them.

I've setting the consume container white space property to both true and false for the report and it makes no difference.

I can't add the textboxes to a tablix as this is a subreport that takes parameters and cannot have a datasource or dataset.

Any ideas on how to get rid of that whitespace when only one or a few lines are visible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a table to your subreport if you don't mind making a trip to the database. If you set the underlying query of the table's dataset to something like SELECT 1=1 then it will execute and return immediately and allow you to gain better control with a fluid layout.

Comment: Ya I've considered that but we don't want any extra calls to the DB as this could potentially be called thousands of times per day

Comment: Thousands of times a day doesn't sound like a lot, especially for `select 1`